# SQL Server connection over VPN not responding

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string, vpn, remote-connection

I would like to connect my VB.net application remotely with SQL database server which is placed on different location.

I installed LogMeIn Hamachi on both the server and client machine and joined existing network on the client machine.

I followed the steps provided in this [tutorial](https://www.sixbitsoftware.com/docs/webhelp_prosb/Sharing_a_Database_Over_a_Virtual_Private_Network_(VPN).htm) to enable TCP connection for SQL Server installed on server machine.

I used the following connection string and called `Hascon()` on windows form load event to test the connection. Either I am not getting any error also the application is not responding when I build the VB.net application.

```
Private conn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=IP address provided by Hamachi,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=SIIU;User ID=sa;Password=12345;"}
Public Function Hascon() As Boolean
        Try
            Sconn.Open()
            Return True
            Sconn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
End Function
```

I have searched in the Internet and tried all the possible solutions but non of solved the problem.

What could be the problem?  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour] and also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple function like this to test your connection:

**Note about Hamachi:**

> Remember if you use Hamachi you might need to authorize the port in
>   the firewall and anti-virus as well as on your box.

Here there is no need for the `con.Close()` since I implemented `Using` which is what you should always do for `IDisposable`.

```
Public Function IsConnectionPossible(ByVal ConnectionString As String) As Boolean
    Dim Result As Boolean = False
    Try
        Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            'Open the connection
            Try
                con.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
            'Get the state
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                Result = True
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return Result
End Function
```

And you can simply call like this:

```
IsConnectionPossible("Data Source=IP address provided by Hamachi,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=SIIU;User ID=sa;Password=12345;")
```

Note this function will purely test the connection it won't be practical to implement this function to open connections for future uses. For that I would recommend using a class.

Comment: I configured the firewall to allow the sql server and the Port number 1433, TCP and 1434, UDP before. I wrote the above sample code and called IsConnectionPossible() on button click event , its not responding.

Comment: @user8328 if you need help wee need information is not responding wont help much. do a debug step by step using a breakpoint and see which line makes it stuck

Comment: I used Try ...Catch ...but it's not throwing error. How could I do that will you help me...Thanks

Comment: @user8328 Read what i said: **QUOTE:**  `if you need help wee need information is not responding wont help much. do a debug step by step using a breakpoint and see which line makes it stuck`

Comment: Please help me how can I do step by step debug using break point. I'm new to vb.net.

Comment: did you try google?: https://www.google.fr/search?q=vb.net+using+breakpoint also https://www.google.fr/search?q=vb.net+step+through+code